# How can I achieve a body that is skinny but ripped? (Model body, Swimmer body)

Tags: workout-routines, diet, workout, bodybuilding, physique

I have recently been working out lately to begin a career in modeling, and I was curious as to how I can achieve a bigger body than what I am currently at right now which is around 135 lbs and a low body fat index. **BUT** I don't really want to BULK on a huge amount of weight. I want to stay lean and get ripped. I have tried doing research on YouTube and other websites but they never seem to hit the nail on the head. I haven't seen one video that has provided information on this body style and how to achieve it what so ever. Below I have a picture as to show what I am talking about more below.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, he is skinny but ripped. He's not huge and overly muscular, he's toned, skinny and has a lot of vascularity. So my question is, is how can I achieve this body style, being skinny, but ripped and vascular? Is there a specific workout routine? A specific diet? etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to build muscle, there's no way around it. Building muscle is a long term process and commitment. If in your pursuit to build muscle you accumulate more fat than you are comfortable with, just cut for a little while and you'll be fine. Losing fat is a relatively super quick process compared to building muscle. A man might spend years, or even his entire life trying to gain 30 lbs of muscle, but losing 30 lbs of fat might take a year at the absolute most if you're going super slow, but being consistent. So what should you do?

1. Train like a bodybuilder.

- Why? So that you can acquire your desired level of musculature in the shortest period of time. This will likely still take a long time (1-3 years), but if your goal is to improve your physique then you should train like those who are the best at improving their physiques.
- How? Consistency and sustainability are the most important factors. Behind them are good form (you should feel your target muscles working), volume (more is generally better within a recoverable range), and intensity (every set should be taken within a few reps of failure).

2. Eat in a surplus.

- Why? The muscle that you put on your frame has to come from somewhere. If you're already thin, your body will be more resistant to losing fat and therefore it isn't as suitable for providing the necessary energy that muscle needs to grow. Because of this, the extra energy needs to come from your diet.
- How? A big surplus will more than maximize how much muscle your body can grow (your training dictates whether it will or not), but it also comes with gaining more fat. A small surplus won't maximize muscle growth, but it also comes with less fat accumulation. As a general rule, aiming to gain 1% of your weight each month won't be too much or too little.

Comment: So leading with your summary... When do I know when to stop lifting for example, if I am doing bicep curls with 15lb on each dumbbell and I do too many reps (meaning it's too light) eventually I will feel my muscle working, but what if I do 25lb on each and it's to the point where I am not making more than 8 reps but I still feel the muscle working, when should I know when to stop and how can I target a comfortable weight?

Comment: @fbleb - Historically the concept of a "hypertrophy range" has been used as a reference for the best loading range with which to build muscle (which is 6-12 reps), but more recent research has shown that both light and heavy loads (essentially any rep range) may be used for hypertrophy training. This is assuming that each set is taken sufficiently close to failure, this means either stopping upon hitting the point of failure or stopping within a few reps of failure (no more than 3 as a general rule) for all of your sets. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28834797/

Comment: As a nice resource to reference back to, Renaissance Periodization has put out a pretty in depth series of guides for hypertrophy. https://renaissanceperiodization.com/hypertrophy-training-guide-central-hub/

Answer (score 0):

Yu can build muscle and lose fat at the same, but not that much muscle and you will look really skinny and ripped.... Think a shredded feather weight  twink like Bruce lee or any slave ever in human history... All bone and a little muscle.

If you are younger than 20-22 I would avoid any dieting and instead eat as much as possible. Because lack of nutrition can result in  stunted growth.

Getting skinny is easy and everyone who doesn't suffer from mental illnesses like eating disorders can do it.
Getting taller when you stunted your growth permanently, well... That it's not possible without surgery.

So for now I just suggest to eat as much as you want, maybe more than your natural appetite if you are young, train and bulk... Get big then stop and you will naturally lean out if you stop force feeding yourself.

If you are already an adult, just track your calories and eat in a maintenance or deficit while training heavy.

Comment: A shredded twink or a slave is the best example you could come up with?

Comment: _ just eat as much as you want_: I would not recommend that, it's the road to getting fat instead of fit. Better eat a proper amount of nutrients as mentioned in the other answer.